# SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor Not Injecting Spring Beans to Message Driven Bean : NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jms, ejb-3.0

I have gone through most resources and tried to the following mechanism to get the Spring Bean to my MDB.

```
    @MessageDriven(name = "FileMDB")
    @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
    public class FileMessageBean implements MessageListener {

        @Autowired
        private IContextLoader contextLoader;

        @Override
        public final void onMessage(final Message message) {

        }
    }
```

My beanRefContext.xml is in the classpath of a JAR File Which is a dependency of a WAR file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:channel-integration-context.xml" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The channel-integration-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's 
        @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @Resource. -->
    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->

    <!-- AOP Annotation -->     
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <!-- File Adapter -->
    <import resource="classpath:channel-dao-beans.xml" />

    <!-- JMS Beans -->
    <import resource="classpath:jms-beans.xml" />

    <!-- Data JNDI Beans -->
    <import resource="classpath:datasource-jndi-beans.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fdc.channelintegration" />

    <bean id="contextLoader" class="com.fdc.channelintegration.util.SpringContextLoader">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am using Websphere 8.5 and my MDB is triggering properly. Still the contextLoader is not injected to the MDB and I am getting a NullPointerException.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Didn't you forget to put `@Cmponent` or `@Service` annotation on your IContextLoader class so spring annotation processor could find it?
2. `<context:annotation-config />` is commented out. Return it back to your context file and remove `@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)`
3. Remove defenition of the bean from the context file: 
   `<bean id="contextLoader" class="com.fdc.channelintegration.util.SpringContextLoader"/>`

Comment: Thanks, small question. why remove SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor? Its suppose to inject the spring bean to the EJB right? Bit confused.

Comment: <context:annotation-config /> should enable annotation bean definition reader. Looks like you are using default (Singleton) scope so autowired dependencies shoul be injected when the context is tarting up. But I can be mistaken if it is a EJB.